# Customize a knitr theme for latex

Tags: r, themes, latex, knitr

[Env: Windows 7, R Studio 0.98-977, R 3.1.1, all packages up-to-date]

In an Rprofile file for a book (sourced in the .Rnw file for each child chapter) I specify the syntax highlighting theme I want for LaTeX output:

```
opts_knit$set(out.format = "latex")
knit_theme$set("seashell")    # light salmon background color
```

However, the result in my document differs from what I see for this theme in 
[knitr themes overview](http://rclickhandbuch.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/knitrthemesoverview.pdf)

That is, the generated `book.tex` file contains the following definitions of colors (these seem to match `knit_theme$get("default")`)

```
\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.345, 0.345, 0.345}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.686,0.059,0.569}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.192,0.494,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textit{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.345,0.345,0.345}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.373,0.58}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.353,0.396}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.333,0.667,0.333}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.737,0.353,0.396}{\textbf{#1}}}%
```

Whereas, in an R console, I get the following for this theme:

```
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(out.format = "latex")
thm <- knit_theme$get("seashell")  
cat(thm$highlight)

\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0.078,0.576}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0.078,0.576}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.161,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.404,0.404,0.404}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.18,0.545,0.341}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.18,0.545,0.341}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.412,0.412,0.412}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.561}{#1}}% 
>
```

All the colors here differ from what appears in my .tex file.  I can't tell why this is so.  (I think it is because the knitr theme is written to the .tex file in the preamble, before my `knit_theme$set()` gets executed.)

- Where in a top-level .Rnw file does `knit_theme$set()` have to be run to take effect?
- After I run `knit2pdf` on my book, how can I determine what knitr theme is currently set?
- More generally, how can I customize a theme? I'd be happy with the default theme if I could change the color used for `\hlkwd` from red to blue, or with seashell if I could boldface function names for `\hlwkd`.